# Discord.js - TypeError: message.delete is not a function (while deleting a reply to a command in DM)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
async execute(interaction) {
        const number = interaction.options.getInteger('number');
        if (number <= 0) {
            await interaction.reply('Give me an integer greater than 0! (Natural number)');
            await wait(5000);
            await interaction.deleteReply();
            return;
        }
        await interaction.reply('0');
        for (let i = 1; i < number; i++) {
            await wait(1000);
            await interaction.editReply(`${i}`);
        }
        await wait(1000);
        try {
// ###(The below part does not work)###
            await interaction.editReply(`Done! I counted to ${number}`)
                .then(message => setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000))
// ###(The above part does not work)###
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                    interaction.reply('There was an error while deleting the message!');
                });
        }
        catch (error) {
            await interaction.editReply('Failed to delete the message');
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
```

This gives an error while trying to delete a reply message in DM on Discord:

`TypeError: message.delete is not a function`

However it perfectly works in server channel. I would use `deleteReply()` but this does not work when you have edited the reply with `editReply()`. I should note though that `deleteReply()` for deleting a message that has not being edited works on DM and servers.

Comment: In a DM, a bot can only delete messages that it sends, it can not delete messages sent to it. If you are trying to delete the message that the bot sends then please update your code sample to provide the code that sends a message via DM as what you have posted is the response shown in reply to an interaction.

Comment: This is the function that gets executed when the command "count" is used.

Comment: Ok but according to your message, you are doing this in a DM, interactions do not occur in a DM, only messages

Comment: I don't know, I am just learning from Discordjs guide and trying things out. Replying and editing the reply in DM works but deleting it with message.delete() does not work. However deleteReply() works but unfortunately when you use editReply() you cannot use deleteReply()